# Material buttons steal clicks from a view that is declared after them in layout hierarchy

Tags: android, material-design, android-button, android-framelayout

I want to hide some part of the content under a scrim (like in drawer layout).
The MaterialComponents buttons that are under this scrim view are receiving clicks to the scrim view, and that is a major problem.

content scrim view:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/scrim"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

button that steals clicks:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/add_at_start"
    android:theme="@style/ButtonArrowShapedLeft"
    style="@style/ButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:text="Add"
    android:visibility="gone"
    tools:visibility="visible"
    app:icon="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/container"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/container" />
```

I already established that the problem lies within the button being elevated. 
If I set the elevation of the scrim even to `2dp`, the button receives no clicks, despite the fact it has probably more dp of elevation than the scrim view.
But this does not solve my problem, it actually makes it worse, because the scrim view now covers everything on the screen, even the content that is way later in layout hierarchy.

I know I can just disable the buttons when the content scrim is visible, but this just doesn't seem right and the buttons feeling entitled to stealing clicks just because of some ludicrous elevation actually angries me enough to seek help.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
android:id="@+id/add_at_start"
android:theme="@style/ButtonArrowShapedLeft"
style="@style/ButtonStyle"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
android:text="Add"
android:visibility="gone"
android:clickable="true"
tools:visibility="visible"
app:icon="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/container"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/container" />
```

Comment: This doesn't work, why should it work? you added `android:clickable="true"`, I don't get how this should change anything

Comment: that will prevent the click when its under the scrim view